# How can I fix the Error: spawn php-cgi ENOENT

Tags: php, node.js, express, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt with php-express and I'm trying to test my php script but an error is persisting for many hours and I can't find the issue.

*server.cjs : *

```
const express = require("express");
const expressPhp = require("express-php");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const phpScriptsPath = path.join(__dirname, "/api-php");

const phpCgiPath = "/usr/local/bin/php-cgi";

app.use("/api-php", expressPhp.cgi(phpScriptsPath, phpCgiPath));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serveur en cours d'exécution sur le port ${port}`);
});
```

**php is installed using Homebrew on MacOs**

```
which php-cgi
/usr/local/bin/php-cgi

php-cgi -v   
PHP 8.3.3 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Feb 13 2024 15:41:14)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.3.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

**and the error that I'm facing : **

```
Error: spawn php-cgi ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn php-cgi',
  path: 'php-cgi',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

I tried to create php logs using php.ini but even if the file is created and full permission is accorded, no error logs is put in the file.

I found a ENOENT debug function and this is what I got  :

```
spawn called
[Arguments] {
  '0': 'php-cgi',
  '1': [],
  '2': {
    env: {
      SERVER_SIGNATURE: 'NodeJS server at localhost',
      PATH_INFO: '',
      PATH_TRANSLATED: '',
      SCRIPT_NAME: '/test.php',
      SCRIPT_FILENAME: '/Users/satyr/Documents/Projet WEB/projet_web/api-php/test.php',
      REQUEST_FILENAME: '/Users/satyr/Documents/Projet WEB/projet_web/api-php/test.php',
      SCRIPT_URI: '/test.php',
      URL: '/test.php',
      SCRIPT_URL: '/test.php',
      REQUEST_URI: '/test.php',
      REQUEST_METHOD: 'POST',
      QUERY_STRING: '',
      CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/json',
      CONTENT_LENGTH: '155',
      AUTH_TYPE: '',
      AUTH_USER: '',
      REMOTE_USER: '',
      ALL_HTTP: 'HTTP_HOST: localhost:3001\n' +
        'HTTP_ACCEPT: application/json, text/plain, */*\n' +
        'HTTP_SEC_FETCH-SITE: same-site\n' +
        'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9\n' +
        'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate\n' +
        'HTTP_SEC_FETCH-MODE: cors\n' +
        'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE: application/json\n' +
        'HTTP_ORIGIN: http://localhost:3000\n' +
        'HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.0 Safari/605.1.15\n' +
        'HTTP_REFERER: http://localhost:3000/\n' +
        'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH: 155\n' +
        'HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive\n' +
        'HTTP_SEC_FETCH-DEST: empty\n',
      ALL_RAW: 'host: localhost:3001\n' +
        'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\n' +
        'sec-fetch-site: same-site\n' +
        'accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9\n' +
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate\n' +
        'sec-fetch-mode: cors\n' +
        'content-type: application/json\n' +
        'origin: http://localhost:3000\n' +
        'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.0 Safari/605.1.15\n' +
        'referer: http://localhost:3000/\n' +
        'content-length: 155\n' +
        'connection: keep-alive\n' +
        'sec-fetch-dest: empty\n',
      SERVER_SOFTWARE: 'NodeJS',
      SERVER_NAME: 'localhost',
      SERVER_ADDR: '127.0.0.1',
      SERVER_PORT: 8011,
      GATEWAY_INTERFACE: 'CGI/1.1',
      SERVER_PROTOCOL: '',
      REMOTE_ADDR: '::1',
      REMOTE_PORT: '',
      DOCUMENT_ROOT: '',
      INSTANCE_ID: '',
      APPL_MD_PATH: '',
      APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH: '',
      IS_SUBREQ: '',
      REDIRECT_STATUS: 1,
      HTTP_HOST: 'localhost:3001',
      HTTP_ACCEPT: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'HTTP_SEC_FETCH-SITE': 'same-site',
      HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9',
      HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: 'gzip, deflate',
      'HTTP_SEC_FETCH-MODE': 'cors',
      HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/json',
      HTTP_ORIGIN: 'http://localhost:3000',
      HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.0 Safari/605.1.15',
      HTTP_REFERER: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH: '155',
      HTTP_CONNECTION: 'keep-alive',
      'HTTP_SEC_FETCH-DEST': 'empty'
    }
  }
}
Error: spawn php-cgi ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn php-cgi',
  path: 'php-cgi',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to the spawn process for `php-cgi`. To troubleshoot and resolve the error, you should follow these steps:

1. Check the php-cgi Path:
   Ensure that the path to `php-cgi` is correct. Based on the information you provided, the path seems to be `/usr/local/bin/php-cgi`. Double-check this path to ensure it is correct.
2. Verify PHP-CGI Installation:
   Confirm that the `php-cgi` binary is installed and accessible. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

   ```
   which php-cgi
   ```
3. Verify PHP-CGI Version:
   Check the version of `php-cgi` to ensure it is properly installed and accessible. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

   ```
   php-cgi -v
   ```
4. Check Permissions:
   Ensure that the user running the Node.js server has the necessary permissions to access the `php-cgi` binary and execute it.
5. Update the Path:
   If the path to `php-cgi` is incorrect, update the `phpCgiPath` variable in your `server.cjs` file to the correct path.

Comment: I've already tried this. I went to the folder and the php-cgi file is located there. I've added the { shell: true } option to the spawn function, and the spawn works. But now I have a 200 response code at any php call, and the data is null. I just try to connect to the database, so it's not working for now.